# Proof involving gcds.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is in a past exam paper i'm studying for....

Let $a,b$ be positive integers. Let $q,r$ be non-negative integers such that $a = bq + r$

$a$)  show that $2^a-1 = ((2^{bq} - 1)/(2^b-1))\cdot 2^r\cdot (2^b-1) + 2^r-1$

$b)$  Hence prove that $\text{gcd}(2^a-1,2^b-1) = \text{gcd}(2^b-1,2^r-1)$

I have $a)$, although somewhat convoluted.
For $b)$, i have it in my head that we need to show that LHS divides RHS and RHS divides LHS... but i'm missing something.

... any takers?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the equation in part a) says that: if $n\mid 2^a-1$, and $ n\mid 2^b-1$ then $n\mid 2^r-1$. This shows $\text{gcd}(2^a-1,2^b-1)\mid \text{gcd}(2^b-1,2^r-1)$.

And it also says that if $n\mid 2^b-1$, and $n\mid 2^r-1$, then $n\mid 2^a-1$. This implies that $\text{gcd}(2^b-1,2^r-1)\mid \text{gcd}(2^a-1,2^b-1)$. From these we have the conclusion.